# Docker overrides the IP address of my own manually created bridge

Tags: docker, bridge

I am trying to **set docker up to connect all containers to my own manually created bridge (br0)**, I don't want docker to create or edit anything in my bridge, because I have other services which uses and depends on my bridge (like OpenVPN) therefore I prefer to create the bridge using my own bash script.

The problem comes when I start docker service, **docker changes my bridge IP address** from what I want **(192.168.1.10)** to something else address(169.254.x.x)!!!

**My Docker version 1.12.1, build 23cf638**

## The steps I did

### Bridge creation:

```
sudo brctl addbr br0
sudo brctl addif br0 eth0
sudo ip addr del 192.168.1.10/24 dev eth0
sudo ip addr add 192.168.1.10/24 dev br0 
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev br0
```

I also deleted the default docker0 brdige.

### Tell docker to use my br0 instead of the default docker0:

Passing ***-b br0*** parameter to dockerd.service starting script to tell docker that I want him to use my br0:

```
sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/overlay.conf
```

I edited ExecStart to be like this:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --storage-driver=overlay -H fd:// -b=br0
```

and then:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

And now when I check my **br0 IP, it is NOT 192.168.1.10 any more, it is back to 172.17.x.x**, and when I try to change it now manually back to 192.168.1.10, the interfaces in containers keeps using 169.254.x.x instead of the IP I want.

P.s. when I check where are the interfaces of my containers: `brctl show`, **they are really in my br0** (that means docker accepted -b br0 paramter, but it just ignores or override my intended IP address).

I just want docker to use my br0 with the intended IP address 192.168.1.10.

My need is that all my containers get and IP address in the range I want.
Thanks in advance.

## Edited:

### My /var/log/daemon.log

```
Oct 10 20:41:12 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping Docker Application Container Engine...
Oct 10 20:41:12 raspberrypi dockerd[976]: time="2016-10-10T20:41:12.067551389Z" level=info msg="Processing signal 'terminated'"
Oct 10 20:41:12 raspberrypi dockerd[976]: time="2016-10-10T20:41:12.128388194Z" level=info msg="stopping containerd after receiving terminated"
Oct 10 20:41:13 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Oct 10 20:41:13 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping Docker Socket for the API.
Oct 10 20:41:13 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Closed Docker Socket for the API.
Oct 10 20:41:13 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Oct 10 20:41:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Withdrawing address record for 169.254.124.135 on br0.
Oct 10 20:41:50 raspberrypi dhcpcd[698]: br0: removing IP address 169.254.124.135/16
Oct 10 20:41:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface br0.IPv4 with address 169.254.124.135.
Oct 10 20:41:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Interface br0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Oct 10 20:41:50 raspberrypi dhcpcd[698]: br0: deleting route to 169.254.0.0/16
Oct 10 20:41:52 raspberrypi ntpd[723]: Deleting interface #7 br0, 169.254.124.135#123, interface stats: received=0, sent=0, dropped=0, active_time=516 secs
Oct 10 20:41:52 raspberrypi ntpd[723]: peers refreshed
Oct 10 20:42:58 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface br0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.19.
Oct 10 20:42:58 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: New relevant interface br0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Oct 10 20:42:58 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.19 on br0.IPv4.
Oct 10 20:43:00 raspberrypi ntpd[723]: Listen normally on 8 br0 192.168.1.19 UDP 123
Oct 10 20:43:00 raspberrypi ntpd[723]: peers refreshed
Oct 10 20:43:15 raspberrypi systemd[1]: getty@tty1.service has no holdoff time, scheduling restart.
Oct 10 20:43:15 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping Getty on tty1...
Oct 10 20:43:15 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Getty on tty1...
Oct 10 20:43:15 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Getty on tty1.
Oct 10 20:43:21 raspberrypi systemd[1]: getty@tty1.service has no holdoff time, scheduling restart.
Oct 10 20:43:21 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping Getty on tty1...
Oct 10 20:43:21 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Getty on tty1...
Oct 10 20:43:21 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Getty on tty1.
Oct 10 20:44:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Docker Socket for the API.
Oct 10 20:44:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Listening on Docker Socket for the API.
Oct 10 20:44:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Oct 10 20:44:31 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:31.887581128Z" level=info msg="libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 1543"
Oct 10 20:44:32 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:32.903109872Z" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver \"overlay\""
Oct 10 20:44:32 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:32.950908429Z" level=info msg="Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds"
Oct 10 20:44:32 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:32.951611338Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support swap memory limit."
Oct 10 20:44:32 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:32.951800086Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support kernel memory limit."
Oct 10 20:44:32 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:32.951906179Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup cfs period"
Oct 10 20:44:32 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:32.951993522Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup cfs quotas"
Oct 10 20:44:32 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:32.952173520Z" level=warning msg="Unable to find cpuset cgroup in mounts"
Oct 10 20:44:32 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:32.952372059Z" level=warning msg="mountpoint for pids not found"
Oct 10 20:44:32 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:32.953406319Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Oct 10 20:44:32 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:32.970612440Z" level=info msg="Firewalld running: false"
Oct 10 20:44:32 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:32.953406319Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Oct 10 20:44:32 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:32.970612440Z" level=info msg="Firewalld running: false"
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.19 on br0.
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface br0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.19.
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Interface br0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface br0.IPv4 with address 169.254.124.135.
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: New relevant interface br0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Registering new address record for 169.254.124.135 on br0.IPv4.
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:33.715576231Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:33.715837582Z" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:33.715921435Z" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=23cf638 graphdriver=overlay version=1.12.1
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:33.754984356Z" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
Oct 10 20:44:34 raspberrypi ntpd[723]: Listen normally on 9 br0 169.254.124.135 UDP 123
Oct 10 20:44:34 raspberrypi ntpd[723]: Deleting interface #8 br0, 192.168.1.19#123, interface stats: received=0, sent=0, dropped=0, active_time=94 secs
Oct 10 20:44:34 raspberrypi ntpd[723]: peers refreshed
```

The interesting part is the last part (I recopied it here bellow):

```
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.19 on br0.
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface br0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.19.
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Interface br0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface br0.IPv4 with address 169.254.124.135.
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: New relevant interface br0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Registering new address record for 169.254.124.135 on br0.IPv4.
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:33.715576231Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:33.715837582Z" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:33.715921435Z" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=23cf638 graphdriver=overlay version=1.12.1
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:33.754984356Z" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
Oct 10 20:44:34 raspberrypi ntpd[723]: Listen normally on 9 br0 169.254.124.135 UDP 123
Oct 10 20:44:34 raspberrypi ntpd[723]: Deleting interface #8 br0, 192.168.1.19#123, interface stats: received=0, sent=0, dropped=0, active_time=94
```

Comment: What version of Docker are you using, and does it behave like this when you use an empty network that you manually specify? This may be an environmental problem (in that your network might have anomaly that Docker is using to reject it), or it could be a bug. Need more information to make a general assessment.

Comment: @SmallLoanOf1M My Docker version 1.12.1, build 23cf638, actually I don't know, but I tried a diffrent range: 192.168.5.1 instead 192.168.1.1 and it bahaves the same.

Comment: Let's check your system logs. It will be different depending on your distribution, but this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969435/where-is-the-docker-daemon-log

Comment: @SmallLoanOf1M I edited my question and attached my daemin.log, could you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

In my case
- I uninstalled avahi-daemon
- I uninstalled connman (saw an error in /var/log/daemon.log) and network-manager

After rebooting (maybe not necessary) the 169.254.x.x-Address wasn't assigned anymore and I was able to work again

(check the `tail -f daemon.log` while starting the container!)

Answer (score -1):

Your Docker is starting a DHCP client on the `br0` interface, which causes it to try to fetch an IP address for the interface. This is indicated by the `169.254.x.x` IP address, which is the autoconfiguration IP address used by DHCP.

You need to check your configuration files so that DHCP is disabled.

Comment: Could you guide me where can I do that please?

Comment: You will not learn things required for professional system administration work by reading guides and doing things without understanding the fundamental concepts. You should read Docker documentation.

Comment: It will be easier if I started from a working version, I have been trying to over come that problem for one week deeping in documetation of docker, but with no success, I didn't know that it can be related to dhcp, I will try to find that in one hour when I go back home.

Comment: I really appreciate if you send me a link about that, I did some search but I didn't find anything useful.